# Ternary operators in AJAX initialization not setting appropriately

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, firefox, ternary

I'm working with some AJAX calls, which connect properly, however if I attempt to use a ternary operator in the initialization of the call, the operator does not set properly. Specifically, I'm trying to dynamically set the async parameter. The AJAX call refuses to accept the ternary version of the async unless it's specified beforehand. This is specific to Firefox. Here's an example:

Server receives the async call as true, regardless if I specify the `async = false;`.

```
function(url, type, async) {
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: type,
        async: async ? async : true
    });
}
```

Works correctly:

```
function(url, type, async) {
    var async = async ? async : true;
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: type,
        async: async
    });
}
```

Although the code is working when I specify it beforehand, I do not understand why a ternary operator won't work in this situation. I would love an explanation as to why it is required to be specified beforehand and not in the call itself.

Thank you,
Ben

Comment: The `? :` cannot reliably be used as in "if the argument is given" as there can be falsy values being passed explicitly (especially in the case of booleans).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your line

```
async: async ? async : true
```

...says: If `async` is truthy, use `async`; otherwise, use `true`. So of course it's always truthy.

If your goal is to default to `async: true` when `async` isn't given at all, do this:

```
async: typeof async === "undefined" ? true : async
```

That will use the value of `async` if it's not `undefined`, or `true` if it is.

---

All due respect, I don't think the second version does anything differently to the first version, I think that must be observational error. This code emulates what you're doing, and always shows `obj.bar` as being `true`:

```
jQuery(function($) {

  function foo1(bar) {
    var obj = {
      bar: bar ? bar : true
    };
    display("(1) obj.bar = " + obj.bar);
  }

  function foo2(bar) {
    var bar = bar ? bar : true;
    var obj = {
      bar: bar
    };
    display("(2) obj.bar = " + obj.bar);
  }

  foo1(false);
  foo1(true);
  foo2(false);
  foo2(true);

  function display(msg) {
    $("<p>").html(String(msg)).appendTo(document.body);
  }
});
```

[Live copy](http://jsbin.com/ixiced) | [source](http://jsbin.com/ixiced/edit)

(It's probably worth noting that the `var` part of the `var async` in your second example — and the `var bar` in my emulation of it — is ignored. No `var` is created, the argument is used directly.)

Comment: Aah, of course it would land as a constant true. Thank you for the clarification on my oversight :)

Answer (score 1):

This happens because the expression will always evaluate to some truthy value.  If you pass a falsy value to your function, you end up passing `true` to `$.ajax`.  You can avoid this problem by using a strict equality check for `false`.

Try `async === false ? false : true`.

Of course, [you should ***never*** use synchronous XHR requests](http://kellegous.com/j/2007/02/12/no-we-dont-do-s/).